# button bar similar to twitter app for android

Tags: android, buttonbar

I want to obtain a similar tab effect with the button bar of twitter app.

I wish to click on a button and change the view down. I can switch activity but I think It's wrong, or not?

The top bar have to be fix like a frame. Like this:

[image]

Ok now I post a part of my idea (i found something similar here: http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-development-answers-tutorials-code-snippets/1515-how-i-open-image-imagebutton.html)

code:

```
        newsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.news);
        newsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // on click go to the news view (no activity yet)
            setContentView(R.layout.news);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Better way is to provide a link to the screen shoot..!!

Comment: I want to obtain the same behaviour like using tabs, but without tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the [Google IO App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.iosched&hl=en)?

If so, the Source Code is freely available [here](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/).

---

Okay, a little tour on how Google does it:

1. The `activity_home.xml`-layout
   [includes](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/activity_home.xml#21) (Line 21) the
   `actionbar.xml`-layout (This is done
   in every Layout so the Actionbar
   must not always be duplicated).
2. The `actionbar.xml`-Layout
   [creates](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/actionbar.xml#17) a `LinearLayout` for
   the UI-Elements.
3. Then, for example the
   [HomeActivity](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/HomeActivity.java#58)-Activity sets
   the content view to the
   `activity_home.xml`-layout, receives
   an ActivityHelper-class and calls
   its `setupActionBar()`-method.
4. The mantioned `ActivityHelper`-class
   is in the `hg/  android/ src/ com/
   google/ android/ apps/ iosched/
   util/`-package and has the
   [setupActionBar()-method](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/ActivityHelper.java#135) which
   creates the Action bar.

This might be easier then it looks. Read your way through the Source Code and try it yourself.

Comment: I've already read some of that and it's useful but I prefer a more simple and short example, if it's possible.

Comment: I want to obtain the same behaviour like using tabs, but without tabs

Comment: I added a detailed tour on how Google did it. See if you can implement this yourself.

Comment: my question it' a little bit different.. I want to click on a button and change view below

Comment: Something like a Frame in HTML?

Comment: @lukas: yes like a frame in html

Comment: Does the mentioned Twitter this, too? I'm not sure if this can easily be archived...

Comment: twitter app change the view below when button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I think these controls are Radio Button/ Radio Group with customization.