# TabBar disappears when starting new intent in android app

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have an Android application with four tabs. When I'm in one of the tabs, click a button which starts a new intent and go to the next view, the tabbar disappears. Any suggestions to how I can prevent that from happening? I want to have the tabbar visible no matter where the user is in the application.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include the tabs (is it a TabHost?) in the layout for each of your Activities. Perhaps what you really want to be doing is switching tabs within the TabHost rather than launching a new Activity...

You can do this by using [TabHost.setCurrentTab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29)

You might also be interested in doing something like the button bar at the top of the Twitter app.  Some details on implementing that can be found here: [button bar similar to twitter app for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533434/button-bar-similar-to-twitter-app-for-android)